# Nearest Value Between Tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a relation:

```
CREATE TABLE mag (
pg_id serial,
nt numeric,
time numeric
);
```

Containing a few tuples:

```
INSERT INTO mag
(nt, time)
VALUES (10,100), (11,200), (12,300), (13,400), (14,500);
```

I also have another relation:

```
CREATE TABLE gps (
pg_id serial,
x numeric,
y numeric,
time numeric
);
```

It also contains some tuples:

```
INSERT INTO gps
(x, y, time)
VALUES (500,500,120), (600,600,180), (700,700,190), (800,800,320), (900,900,800);
```

I would like to join the tables.  Each tuple in the `mag` relation should be joined to the tuple in the `gps` relation having the closest value in the `time` field (smallest difference of absolute value).

The catch, of course, is that the real-world relations each contain several thousand tuples, so extra kudos will be awarded for query speed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT m.pg_id, m.nt, m.time mag_time,
 g.*
FROM (
 SELECT m.pg_id, m.time,
        CASE 
          WHEN  min( g2.time ) is null
           THEN max( g1.time )
          WHEN max( g1.time ) is null
           THEN min( g2.time )
          WHEN 
            m.time - max( g1.time )
            <
            min( g2.time ) - m.time 
          THEN max( g1.time )
          ELSE min( g2.time )
         END join_time
   FROM mag m
   LEFT JOIN gps g1
   ON m.time >= g1.time
   LEFT JOIN gps g2
   ON m.time <= g2.time
   GROUP BY m.pg_id, m.time
) AS j
LEFT JOIN mag m
ON j.pg_id = m.pg_id
LEFT JOIN gps g
ON j.join_time = g.time
;
```

Demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/33fc0/17

An index on `gps.time` column **must** be created to speed up this query.
I assume that `mag.pg_id` is the primary key, so the index for this column already exists, 
if no, then this column must be also indexed.

Comment: That seems to return 4 records from the mag relation, rather than all 5 tuples.  Is that what you expected?

Comment: Sorry for the delay.  I am back in the office and am checking your revised solution now.  Thanks again for the input.